Many-To-Many relationship using Realm in React Native Expo
How can I create a local Many-To-Many relationship using Realm in React Native Expo using an intermediatory table?
Example 2 tables:
const products = {
    name: "Products",
    properties: {
        id: "int",
        name: "string",
        price: "int"
    }

const customers = {
    name: "Customers",
    properties: {
        id: "int",
        userName: "string",
        password: "string"
    }

I want to create an intermediatory table named productsCustomers. This table should create a Many-To-Many relationship between the products table and the customers table.
I have tried using the following code to do this:
const productsCustomers = {
    name: "ProductsCustomers",
    properties: {
      id: "int",
      products: { type: "objectId", link: "products" },
      customers: { type: objectId, "link": "customers" }
    }

I have tested this code using Jest:
describe("productsCustomers table", () => {
    let realm;
    beforeEach(() => {
        realm = new Realm({ "schema": [ProductsCustomers] });
    });
    afterEach(async() => {
        realm.write(() => {
            realm.deleteAll();
        });
        await realm.close();
    });
    
    test("Create ProductsCustomers table", () => {
        expect(realm.schema[0].name).toBe("ProductsCustomers");
    });

This produces the error:
Schema validation failed due to the following errors:
    - Property 'Products.customers ' declared as origin of linking objects property 'ProductsCustomers.products' does not exist
    - Property 'Customers.products' declared as origin of linking objects property 'ProductsCustomers.customers ' does not exist


Realm directly supports many<->many relationships. What's the need for the intermediary "table" (there are no tables in Realm - it's noSQL represented by documents/objects)
